# getting weird logs set to syslog after vrealize starts VM

Tags: vmware-esx

I have found some instances of newly spun up VMs spewing a bunch of records out to syslog.  The one I came across recently was a RHE machine running rsyslog.

The times in the syslog records are way off the present ( sometimes in the past and sometimes in the future.  The logs arrive at the syslog host in a single bunch (all within the same second).

Anyone have any idea what is causing this?

I am guessing that it is something to do with the way the VM snapshot was made?  THe logs bare no relationship with the current instantiation and I have now set things up on the receiving server to ignore incoming records that have time more than 60 seconds from current time.